# Is it possible to make livecam from smartphone browser?

Tags: html, html5-video, live-streaming, smartphone

Is it possible to make livecam (video +sound) from smartphone browsers with 6 different people?

I read about html5 but i would like to know how it would work to stream 6 different people from their smartphone to one single html page. These 6 people could live chat all at same time from their smartphone browser.

Would it need a server to host the stream or smartphone is enough powerful to handle all these stream? How it works exactly?

Sorry for so many questions. I am confused. I dont understand very well where is store the streaming. but in fact it is quite clear what i want:

An html page where 6 people can livecam chat at same time on this page from their smartphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to this.  The first is the capture of the camera and microphone.  For that, use the MediaDevice API... specifically getUserMedia.

The next part is connecting bidirectional streams together.  WebRTC is the best technology for this.  It's built for video conferencing.  However, with 6 people you'll need some conferencing server in the middle.  Otherwise, all 6 participants are going to have to send video to each other and it will waste bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: So it is technically possible to make such an html page. Thanks.